# C# WPF FileSaving Exception encountered

Tags: c#, wpf

My issue is that I keep seeing a recurring theme with trying to allow my Notepad clone to save a file. Whenever I try to save a file, regardless of the location on the hard disk, the UnauthorizedAccess Exception continues to be thrown. Below is my sample code for what I've done, and I have tried researching this since last night to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//located at base class level
private const string fileFilter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";

private string currentPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

private void MenuFileSaveAs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
    sfd.Filter = fileFilter;
    sfd.AddExtension = true;
    sfd.InitialDirectory = currentPath;
    sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
    sfd.OverwritePrompt = true;
    sfd.ShowDialog();

    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(currentPath,TxtBox.Text,Encoding.UTF8);     
    }

    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }    

    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Access Denied");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full UnauthorizedAccessException's message? Please post the full exception message.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Kohou_000\Documents' is denied.

With the MessageBox, it says "Access Denied"

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath` returns the path to a **folder**. The first parameter to `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` must be the path to a **file**, not a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines.

```
...
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() != true)
        return;

    try
    {
        using (var stream = sfd.OpenFile())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(TxtBox.Text);
        }
    }
...
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This actually corrected the issue. Thank you very much for the awesome response!

So, by what i'm looking at code wise, you have to convert the textbox's input to a stream of bytes in order for it to save appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the correct path context and file object from the dialog box once the user has hit 'ok'.  Namely verify the user actually hit ok and then use the OpenFile property to see what their file selection is:

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog.HasValue && sfd.ShowDialog)
{
    if (sfd.OpenFile() != null)
    {
        // convert your text to byte and .write()
        sfd.OpenFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I think I may have an idea that correlates with this one.